# How to get token by GoogleAuthUtil.getToken?

Tags: android, eclipse, token, google-oauth

I have problem with GoogleAuthUtil.getToken.

May be I miss something. I read most of the answers, but it did not help me.

**So, what I do:**

1. Register in Google Developers Console [Here](http://clip2net.com/s/6NPI4D)

   - App with package name, for example **su.Company.AppName**
   - I have created keystore, using Eclipse.
   - Create certificate and put Certificate fingerprint (SHA1)
2. I have not marketplace account
3. Using Eclipse project context menu - > Android tools -> Export signet APK i generate Signed APK and install it on Android device via SD card.
   For signing I have used certificate from step 1
4. I have code in App

   ```
   private String SCOPE_BASE = "audience:server:client_id:";
   private String SCOPE;
   private String CLIENT_ID = "140853970719-g5ol9mh39f2trarq7f0qt353gdens3sl.apps.googleusercontent.com";

   SCOPE = SCOPE_BASE + CLIENT_ID;
           try {

               token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, accountName, SCOPE);//accountName - real gmail
           } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
               error= authEx.getMessage();}
   ```
5. I have always received GoogleAuthException  exception with only one world `"Unknown"`

   If I am sending wrong email in accountName I receive error **"Wrong user"**

I do not know what to do next.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Really, 23 days without solutions?

Comment: Did you try this scope instead : ``"oauth2:server:client_id:<SERVER-CLIENT-ID>:api_scope:<SCOPE1> <SCOPE2>"`` ? [link1](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app) [link2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html)